# Why can't I see http request in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I am working in wireshark. I am monitoring the wifi traffic on the same network. We have 6 pc's there and one machine was installed on wireshark to  capture wifi traffic. I got my team mates Ip address in the endpoint list.  My machine have installed wiresahrk. whenever they ping to my machine. my machine ip : 192.168.1.214. and others are: 192.168.1.31, 164,188,242. and they ping a request to my m/c I can capture that request.
And if 192.168.1.188 machine send a http request to a local server to other ip like 164, 31 . I couldn't capture that http request. Its hows only mdns protocol.. here is the screenshot..

Why I can't capture the http request ? Why other team mates IP (188-->164.31) was not capture ?  Anyone please help me

I am working in ubuntu machine.

My router type is : `Belkin Surf N150 Wireless Modem Router, F9J1001 v1.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6LGy.png)

Comment: I'm not really following your question but if you're trying to capture your mate's HTTP request to an external website from your machine running Wireshark than that isn't possible. Perhaps you could clarify your question for us?

Comment: @joeqwerty  not an external website. reuqest to local server

Answer (score 1):

You can't capture the http request to the webserver because it is not going to your machine. You will have to run wireshark/tcpdump on the webserver or some common component in the network like a router.

Comment: Additionally, please read & understand https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you're running tcpdump/wireshark on your laptop, over a WiFi link.

If so, you should know that the traffic from other clients connected to your access point won't show on your connection - unless explicitly addressed to you.

You would need to work from your router.